# More than one drop down messing up jQuery / Bootstrap function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Basically what is going on is I have a fee calculator that tallies up the fees as the user processes through the form. In the example there is a checkbox when clicked it is supposed to pop up a div and show Fees $225 what I am trying to do is add the fee from my drop down that pops open a new window asking if they want to add for that price..

I want it to add the price when they hit accept to my running total on the form.

Correct Example http://jsfiddle.net/hwcu7e05/5/

**This example is incorrect and it is because there is more than one drop down how do I fix this error.. this page has many drop downs on it.. its clear there is something wrong with my jQuery function.
When there is more than one drop down and you select from the fee drop down to add a price you get NaN**

Incorrect Example http://jsfiddle.net/sww393du/

Will someone please tell me what I am skipping or where I am going wrong? I really appreciate any suggestions or advice!!

```
$(function() {
        $('#SPECIAL').on('change', function() {
            if ($('option:selected', this).is('[data-img]')) {

                $('#modal_special').find('.modal-title').html($('option:selected', this).data('name'));
                $('#modal_special').find('.modal-body').html('')
                .append('<img alt="coming soon" src="' + $('option:selected', this).data('img') + '"/><br/><br/>                 Would you like to add this license plate for: $' + $('option:selected', this).data('price') + ' ?')
                .end().modal('show');
            }
        });

        $('.accept').on('click',function() {
            specialFee = $('option:selected').data('price');
            calculateTotal();
            $('#modal_special').modal('hide');
        });
    });
```

Comment: You've got a couple problems going on. One `specialFee = $('option:selected').data('price');` How does your code know *which* selected option to get the price from? Do you want the selected option from the first or second dropdown? Also, when you call calculateTotal, I'd pass in specialFee.

Comment: You aren't grabbing the price from the modal. You're grabbing it from the data-price attribute which only exists on your "SPECIAL" dropdown. You need to be more specific when you're setting specialFee. Something like `#SPECIAL option:selected` might work. http://jsfiddle.net/sww393du/2/

Comment: It seems to work in my jsfiddle link. Or is that not the behavior you wanted?

Comment: Sorry didn't see it yes I got it too work with your fiddle!! post it ill accept the answer thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be specific when you specify which dropdown to get the price from: 
http://jsfiddle.net/sww393du/2/

```
specialFee = $('#SPECIAL option:selected').data('price');
```

Answer (score 2):

Because there are 2 different dropdown menus in your application you need to tell jQuery which drop-down has the selected option that you want!

```
$('.accept').on('click',function() {
        specialFee = $('#SPECIAL option:selected').data('price');
        calculateTotal();
        $('#modal_special').modal('hide');
    });
```

All I did was add #SPECIAL to this section of code and it worked fine; otherwise there are two options available, the month drop-down and the special drop-down. JQuery selects the first "option:selected" that it finds which is the month selector.